# Publish Shapash webapp on public internet

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I have created a dashboard using jupyter-notebook which is currently running on my localhost using the command

```
app = xpl.run_app(host="localhost",port=8050)
```

where `xpl` is the Shapash object.

Now, I would like to host it over the public internet so that everyone can have access to it. Can anyone help me how to expose the dashboard to the internet or on AWS?

If anyone is interested in how to reproduce the scenario to webapp. You can refer to below code:

```
import pandas as pd
from category_encoders import OrdinalEncoder
from shapash.data.data_loader import data_loading
from shapash.explainer.smart_explainer import SmartExplainer
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# Read data
house_df, house_dict = data_loading('house_prices')
y_df = house_df['SalePrice'].to_frame()
X_df = house_df[house_df.columns.difference(['SalePrice'])]

# Convert Categorical into numerical
categorical_features = [col for col in X_df.columns if X_df[col].dtype == 'object']
encoder = OrdinalEncoder(cols=categorical_features).fit(X_df)
X_df=encoder.transform(X_df)

# Split data, train model and predict
Xtrain, Xtest, ytrain, ytest = train_test_split(X_df, y_df, train_size=0.75)
reg = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=200, min_samples_leaf=2).fit(Xtrain,ytrain)
y_pred = pd.DataFrame(reg.predict(Xtest), columns=['pred'], index=Xtest.index)

xpl = SmartExplainer(
    model=reg,
    preprocessing=encoder,
    features_dict=house_dict 
)

xpl.compile(
    x=Xtest,
    y_pred=y_pred,
    y_target=ytest,
)
# To display the webapp locally
app = xpl.run_app(host="localhost", port=8050)
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not look like a SageMaker question. If you want to host a serverless website on AWS see: https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-serverless-web-app-lambda-apigateway-s3-dynamodb-cognito/.

If you do not need to train the model every time and just want to showcase the dashboard I suggest just hosting the code to depict the dashboard.

If you want to train and deploy the model on SageMaker, I see the model is SKLearn. Kindly take a look at this link: https://ram-vegiraju.medium.com/training-and-deploying-custom-scikit-learn-models-on-aws-sagemaker-3de6a2f669f4

Comment: How can I host the code to depict the dashboard?

Comment: Do you just want a static site?

Comment: Yes, I want a way to host the web app